# How to scan a string line, then scan inside that line without creating a nested loop? Java

Tags: java, string

I want to write a code that scan each line of a file, then it takes each line and scan each next token on it (by a specified delimiter), then compare the token with an input, if there is no match it moves to the next line..etc. But, I couldn't think of any other way that doesn't involves making nested loop! Is there any other way, or a better approach?

```
try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(CLOCK_TIME);

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        //scan next line
        //scan all specified tokens from each line
        //if no match repeat, otherwise break
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What kind of token? Also, why is a nested loop not allowed?

Comment: It's allowed but it effects the efficiency of a program, and I prefer to stay away from if it possible. @ElliottFrisch

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner loop, that's what the tool is for (for the life of me, I don't know why you're worried about using it). Just be sure to conserve resources by closing your inner Scanner when you're done with it after the end of the inner loop, and same for your outer Scanner.

```
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(someFile);
while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
   String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
   Scanner innerScanner = new Scanner(line);
   while (innerScanner.hasNext()) {
      // do whatever
   }
   innerScanner.close();
}
fileScanner.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the line with the `split` function, but then you'd still have to use a loop to iterate over the resulting array.

To make it easier to look at, you could just pass the `line` into a function with the inner-nested loop.

i.e.

```
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(someFile);
while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
 String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
 scanLine(line) // call the inner loop function
}
fileScanner.close();

...

private void scanLine(String line) {
  Scanner innerScanner = new Scanner(line);
  while (innerScanner.hasNext()) {
    // inner nested loop code inside separate function
  }
  innerScanner.close();
}
```

With what it sounds like you're tying to do, there's no way to process the line without an inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you want to know if the user input is in a line and skip it if it's not.  Why not use `String.contains()` to find out if the user input is in the line?

```
try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(CLOCK_TIME);

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        if (line.contains(userInput) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```